# PHP str_replace not replacing correctly

Tags: php, string, if-statement, replace, url-rewriting

ok this is my code :

```
<?php if(empty($_GET['keywords']))
    {
        echo "Latest jobs in ".$_GET['loc'];
    } 
    elseif(empty($_GET['loc']))
    {
        echo "Latest ".$_GET['keywords']." jobs";
    } 
    elseif(empty($_GET['keywords']) && ($_GET['loc']))
    {
        echo "BLAH";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Latest ".$_GET['keywords']." jobs in ".$_GET['loc'];
    }
    ?>
```

On the index page there are 2 form fields , keywords & loc
Now, if the user hits the form without entering data 
so $_get['keywords'] & $_get['loc'] are both empty
i want it to echo BLAH

If $_get['keywords'] is empty but $_get['loc'] isnt echo "Latest jobs in ".$_GET['loc'];

If $_get['loc'] is empty but $_get['keywords'] isnt 
echo Latest ".$_GET['keywords']." jobs";

and if they both contain data I want it to echo "Latest ".$_GET['keywords']." jobs in ".$_GET['loc'];

My .htaccess file contains this

```
RewriteRule jobs/(.*)$ jobs.php?keywords=&loc=$1
RewriteRule (.*)/jobs$ jobs.php?keywords=$1&loc=
RewriteRule (.*)/jobs-in/(.*)$ jobs.php?keywords=$1&loc=$2
```

jobs.php is the page where I want the data above to be echoed
Its for the title formatting etc

Please help guys, Ive spent 3 hours on this so far and all I've got is code block now :(

** STR_REPLACE code below **

```
function search()
{
if(isset($_POST['keywords']) || ($_POST['loc']))
    {
    $replace_array = array(',',' ');
    if(empty($_POST['keywords'])) 
    { 
        $keywords = ''; 
        $loc = str_replace($replace_array,'-',$_POST['loc']);
        header("Location: jobs/$loc");
    } elseif(empty($_POST['loc']))
    {
        $keywords = str_replace($replace_array,'-',$_POST['keywords']); 
        $loc = '';
        header("Location: $keywords/jobs");
    }
    else 
    {
        $keywords = str_replace($replace_array,'-',$_POST['keywords']); 
        $loc = str_replace($replace_array,'-',$_POST['loc']);
        header("Location: $keywords/jobs-in/$loc");
    }
    }   
}
```

Comment: *Um....*, can you show us where `str_replace()` comes into play here? *"PHP str_replace not replacing correctly"*

Comment: updated, apologies

Upon pressing submit it runs the sdearch() function then redirects as appropriate then on the destination page I want it performing teh rewrite

Comment: Your htaccess shows as `jobs.php?keywords` which implies a GET method, and you're using GET arrays in one piece of code, then switching to POST, *why?*. Check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php do a var_dump also. No idea where the POSTs are coming from too, a form most likely, but unknownst to us.

Comment: POST is from the form on index page then when submitted & url rewritten its then pulled from the URL so uses GET

Comment: You've been given an answer below, you'll have to ask him now. I wish you well ;-) *Cheers* oh and add `exit;` after each header, otherwise your code may want to continue to execute.

Answer (score 0):

If both are empty, the first `if` also resolves to true, because `A && B == true` implies `A == true` (basic Boolean logic).

Try this:

```
if(empty($_GET['keywords']) && empty($_GET['loc']))  {
    echo "BLAH";
} elseif(empty($_GET['keywords'])) {
    echo "Latest jobs in ".$_GET['loc'];
} elseif(empty($_GET['loc'])) {
    echo "Latest ".$_GET['keywords']." jobs";
} else {
    echo "Latest ".$_GET['keywords']." jobs in ".$_GET['loc'];
}
```

Finally, what does `str_replace` have to do with this question (or your rewrite rules) ?